# Are there sects of Islam similar to protestants?

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, shiism, islamic-philosophy

I know there are Sunni and Shia as the two major denominations of Islam and Sufi as the more mystical component. Are there any other sects? such as how Protestant denominations find comfort in the belief of sola scriptora are there any Muslim communities that don't use the Hadith?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/are-there-any-schools-of-thought-which-consider-the-science-of-fiqh-to-be-bidah

Comment: The first two generation of Muslims didn't use Hadith, and the Sahaba never compiled Hadiths in books as they did with the Quran. They were called Ahlul Kalam i.e. Kalamullah - Quran.  They were never a sect but the original group.